# How we can handle the WSO2DSS errors?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

We can handle the errors in WSO2ESb using fault sequence its handling in ESB level only how we can handle DSS level errors also like primarykey violation ,input parameter wrong.

We have any separate fault handler for WSO2DSS level else we may handle in WSO2ESB level only.

I am trying in ESB side but I am unable to handle it through fault sequence .

This is DSS level Error how can I handle it:

```
 ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery} -  ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "emp_pkey"
  Detail: Key (eno)=(9) already exists.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "emp_pkey"
  Detail: Key (eno)=(9) already exists.


[2013-03-12 10:45:44,914] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOnlyMessageReceiver} -  Error in in-only message receiver
DS Fault Message: Error in DS non result invoke.
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processNormalQuery'
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: dept_DataService
Location: /dept_DataService.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: insert_dept_operation
Current Params: {deptid=7, deptno=, deptname=hr}
Nested Exception:-
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

The ESb directly sending a message to client.

The message is:

```
{"Exception":"DS Fault Message: Error in DS non result invoke.\nDS Code: DATABASE_ERROR\nNested Exception:-\njavax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processNormalQuery'\nDS Code: DATABASE_ERROR\nSource Data Service:-\nName: dept_DataService\nLocation: \/dept_DataService.dbs\nDescription: N\/A\nDefault Namespace: http:\/\/ws.wso2.org\/dataservice\nCurrent Request Name: insert_dept_operation\nCurrent Params: {deptid=7, deptno=, deptname=hr}\nNested Exception:-\njava.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"\"\n\n"}
```

Comment: it means fault response from DSS sending to client but my intention is i need to customize this into Esb as per my requirment

Answer (score 2):

So here, when an error occurs in DSS, it will send back a SOAP fault to the user, which is, in this case, the ESB. For the ESB, this is still just another message response, and it will not goto the fault sequence, unless you explicitly check the message and do the necessary actions. But from ESB 4.5.0, now you have the option of saying, if the response is a SOAP fault, the execution should switch to the fault sequence. This is explained in detail here [1].

[1] http://maharachchi.blogspot.com/2012/09/now-you-can-send-soapfaults-to-fault.html

Cheers,
Anjana.

Comment: thanx for replay. where i can keep this property in every sequence or intial sequence stage   i got lot of idea about this is this property work in sequence also ..means i have two insertion operations 1st one is insequence level and 2nd insertion is some other sequence level.if 2nd insertion went wrong then only fault sequence evalute..where i can keep this property in every sequence or intial sequence stage

Comment: my scenario is i am using 3 tables to insert..and using Returned genrated key for every insertion..my 1st insertion done succesfully and returned a key using that one i am inserting data into 2nd table but error violated in 2nd table.i want rollback 1st table data also..how we can do this